# Comparing an array to a multi-dimensional array to find an extra element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to do the following.

Assume I have one array.

Array A,

```
-> [0] = A
-> [1] = B
-> [2] = C
```

That I want to compare to a multidimensional array

```
-> [0]
       [0] = 1
       [1] = A
       [2] = B
       [3] = C
-> [1]
       [0] = 2
       [1] = B
       [2] = C
       [3] = A

-> [2]
       [0] = 3
       [1] = C
       [2] = B
       [3] = A
```

I want to compare the first array, to the content in the multidimensional array. As you can see the multidimensional array has a number attached to each combination of letters. I want to make the comparison in a way that I can get the corresponding number of array A out of array B, assuming that they're in array B too. How can I do this?

Comment: "corresponding number of array A out of array B" Can you give Bit more details?

Comment: I want to know what number belongs to array A. So for example, I want the comparison return 1 in this case. I want the number of Array B that has the same elements as array A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public function findSubArray($multiArr, $compArr) {
  foreach ($multiArr as $idx => $arr) { //for each sub array
    $first = array_shift($arr); //take off the first element and store it
    if (count(array_diff($arr, $compArr)) == 0) { //check if the remainder is what you want
      return $first; //if so, return the first element
    }
  } //otherwise loop
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. You made it look so simple! Thanks a bunch!